# ES6 Instantiating a derived class from an existing instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following scenario:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.A = 'A';
  }

  createB() {
    //Create a B instance from this current instance
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.B = 'B';
  }
}

var base = new A();
var derived = new B();

base.A = 'C';

// Create a B instance from A so that
// a new A isn't instantiated and 
// fromInstance.A === 'C'
var fromInstance = base.createB();
```

I would like to be able to create an instance of `B` without having to create a new instance of `A`, but rather use the existing `A` instance.

My goal is to be able to spawn a `B` instance by calling a function within `A`, but also allow a `B` instance to be created directly and handle constructing a default `A`.

How can I achieve something like this when `B` extends `A` and requires `super()` to be called?

Comment: Are you sure that `base.A` property exists ?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the typo in my example. `this.Name` was supposed to be `this.A`

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you're trying to do this, and I'm drawing a blank. You want to instantiate a class without... instantiating a class? What are you trying to _do_, that you think you're need what you describe in the code comment for? Because I'm pretty certain that's not what you actually need.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am applying it to a collection of adapters I am writing for MongoDB's NodeJS driver. There is a `DbClient` base class that handles basic operations, and a derived `DbCollection` class. Ideally, I could directly instantiate a `DbCollection class` and have it automatically create a `DbClient` object as the base, as well as be able to instantiate a `DbCollection` directly from inside of the `DbClient` instance and use it as the base without having to create an entirely new one

Comment: @Haus Are you able to modify these classes, or can you only access the instance?

Comment: @sunny-lan yes, I'm able to modify the classes. For consistency's sake, I would prefer to stick with the ES6 class syntax over function constructors and prototype setting where possible

Comment: I still don't understand, if you have a `class B extends A` then you can do _whatever you like_ in B's `constructor` function, including calling anything that would be available as part of "being an A". Even when your extending class shadows A's functions, you have the `super` keyword. Can you edit your question so that it actually reflects what you're doing, and what you need it to do, rather than classes that use variables with the same names as the class names?

Comment: *"I would like to be able to create an instance of B without having to create a new instance of A, but rather use the existing A instance."* Then you are not looking for inheritance but composition. Inheritance is B is a A. Composition is B has a A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is exactly what you want but it works for your example:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.A = 'A';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.B = 'B';
  }
}

var base = new A();
var derived = new B();

base.A = 'C';

// Create a B instance from A so that
// a new A isn't instantiated and 
// fromInstance.A === 'C'
var fromInstance = new B();
Object.assign(fromInstance, base);

console.log(fromInstance);
```

Here is an alternate solution. It is actually pretty common in C# and Java, but since JS has no method overloading, this is kind of cumbersome and not so nice compared to the above solution:

```
class A {
  constructor(source) {
    if(source){
      //use properties/stuff from source
      this.A=source.A;
    }
    else{
      //only perform initialization if source is not provided
      this.A = 'A';
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(source) {
    super(source);
    this.B = 'B';
  }
}

var base = new A();
var derived = new B();

base.A = 'C';

// Create a B instance from A so that
// a new A isn't instantiated and 
// fromInstance.A === 'C'
var fromInstance = new B(base);

console.log(fromInstance);
```

Basically, there are two versions of the constructor, one that creates a completely new object, and one that pretty much copies an old object.

I think there is a bit of a misunderstanding, every instance of `B` is by definition an instance of `A`, no matter what you do. If you want `super` to be called, you are calling the constructor of `A`, and thus "instantiating" `A`.

Comment: This does solve the main problem at hand, but it would be nice to avoid constructing a brand new `A` instance for the base of `B` when it is just going to be replaced instantly.

Comment: @Haus Regardless of the solution, you are going to have to make 1 `A` instance and N `B` instances no matter what, if I'm not misunderstanding. I'll edit the answer to include an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an instance of `B`, copy the properties of the current instance of `A` to it using `Object.assign` then return it:

```
createB() {
    var b = new B();
    Object.assign(b, this);
    return b;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.A = 'A';
  }

  createB() {
    var b = new B();
    Object.assign(b, this);
    return b;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.B = 'B';
  }
}

var base = new A();
var derived = new B();

base.A = 'C';

var fromInstance = base.createB();

console.log(fromInstance instanceof B);
console.log(fromInstance.A);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you want the new instance's `A` property to reflect the `A` property of the instance that created it, right? You can set this in `createB` since it will be called on `A` instance. This will allow the `B` instance to have a property that shadows the inherited `A`

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
      this.A = 'A';
    }
  
    createB() {
      let b = new B()
      b.A = this.A   // set to the instances 'A'
      return b
    }
  }
  
  class B extends A {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.B = 'B';
    }
  }
  
  var base = new A();
  var derived = new B();
  
  base.A = 'C';
  
  // Create a B instance from A so that
  // a new A isn't instantiated and 
  // fromInstance.A === 'C'
  var fromInstance = base.createB();
  console.log(fromInstance)
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach could copy *all* A instance properties to a new B instance. An even more generic approach would be to copy the B object's properties to temporary storage first, and write them back later, so that if A and B had the same property name, the B object's property would take precedence:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.A = 'A';
  }

  createB() {
     let b = new B();
     let temp = {};
     let aProp, bProp;
     // save own properties of b
     Object.keys( b).forEach( bProp => (temp[bProp]=b[bProp]));
     // install own properties of A instance
     Object.keys( this).forEach( aProp => ( b[aProp]=this[aProp]));
     // write back b properties over A instance properties
     Object.keys( temp).forEach( bProp=> (this[bProp]=temp[bProp]));
     return b;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.B = 'B';
  }
}

var base = new A();
var derived = new B();

base.A = 'C';

// Create a B instance from A so that
// a new A isn't instantiated and 
// fromInstance.A === 'C'
var fromInstance = base.createB();
console.log( "derived.A = %s", derived.A);
console.log( "fromInstance.A = %s", fromInstance.A);
```

Note that in JavaScript terms avoiding Class constructs be syntactically easier because you can change the `prototype` properties of ordinary functions but not Class constructor functions. However you would probably lose the ability to reliably identify `B` instances using `instanceof B`. Using a class expression in `CreateB` has the same problem - returned objects would not share the same Class constructor.